# Images always in middle of container

Tags: html, css

I want the first image to stick to the top of the container and the following images should be below it... top:0; lets the image be..200px above the container and if I just say position:relative its always in the middle...;

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card_left"> 
        <p style="font-size:1.6em; padding: 15px 0;"><b>Title</b></p>
        <p style="font-size:1.2em;">Long text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card_right">
        <img src="../res/images/artikel1bild.PNG"/>
        <img src="../res/images/artikel1bild.PNG"/>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block` so there will be no other images in the same line and `margin: auto` for centering the image

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" />
  <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```css
 img {
  margin: 0, auto;width: 200px;display:inline-block;height:100px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="card_right">
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: the problem  is that the height  of the card right is really big and the images are alway in the middle : but i want them to stick to the top

Comment: the height of the card right depends on the height of your images, check my edited answer to stick your images to the top

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<br />` after each image if you want to stick to HTML:

```
<div class="card_right">
   <img src="../res/images/artikel1bild.PNG"/><br />
   <img src="../res/images/artikel1bild.PNG"/><br />
</div>
```

Or the better way would be to make a separate CSS file and set `display: block;` for your `img` tags:

```
img {
   display: block;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/nk8fbr76/